# PDO print_r() returns 1

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

So I have a PDO and MySQL script that is used to retrieve a result based on the user's username, or screen name, in this case being `e`.

First, I have a function at the beginning of the file that is used to connect to the database. (it is present in a `functions.php` file and `required` at the beginning of each page, thus the globalization). This function doesn't have anything wrong with it (as far as I know).

```
function SQLConnect () {
// Database connection variables
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "dropbox";
$user = "root";
$password = "ethan17458";

// Connect to the database
try {

//put $connect in global scale of document
 global $connect;

 // attempt to connect to database
 $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $password);

// Sets error mode
$connect->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );



} catch (PDOException $e) {

// Retrieves error message if connection fails
echo $e->getMessage();

    }
}
```

This function uses PDO to connect to the database containing the user's information.

Next is the script to retrieve the user's data

```
// Test user in database
$test = "e";


try {

//confirms running of "try" block
echo "tried";

//database information
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "dropbox";
$user = "root";
$password = "ethan17458";




//Prepare statement from connection function
// username_raw is "e"
//username should be e1671797c52e15f763380b45e841ec32 (md5)
$statement = $connect->prepare("SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username_raw` = ':name'");

//create placeholder for prepared statement
$statement->bindParam(":name", $test);

//make the statement fetch in an associative array
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//execute the prepared statement
$statement->execute();

//set $get_result to the fetched statement
$get_result = $statement->fetch();

//attempt to display the data fetched in $get_result
echo "<br />";
echo "<pre>";

//Outputs 1 for some reason
// **not working**
echo print_r($get_result);


echo "</pre>";
echo "<br />";

} catch (PDOException $e) {
//confirm running of "catch" block
echo "caught";

// echo error message
echo $e->getMessage();

}
```

When I run this script I get this output:

```
tried

1
```

In this output, `tried` is the confirmation that the "try" statement was processed, and the `1` is where I start to run into problems.

If the script was working as I would like, the script would retrieve the data `e1671797c52e15f763380b45e841ec32` from the database because it is the column `username` where the `username_raw` is `e`, as is stated in the PDO prepared statement.

The ideal output should be

```
tried

e1671797c52e15f763380b45e841ec32
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just print_r, no echo.

Comment: that outputs nothing.

Comment: `print_r()` displays the output requested __and__ returns a Boolean true, which you're then echoing

Comment: so how do I display the output requested @MarkBaker?

Comment: print_r() should always display the output, in this case the value of `$get_result`, even if that output is a NULL

Comment: Check if any results exist first, fetch probably returning false

Comment: @MarkBaker so `$get_result` doesn't have a value?

Comment: Try using `var_dump()` instead, but not with an echo

Comment: @MarkBaker `var_dump()` returns `bool(false)`

Comment: You've quoted `:name` in your SQL prepared statement, don't quote bound values in prepared statements... that's one of the things that binding handles for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fetch() is returning false, which prints nothing to the screen. This is false because you're getting no results because you're putting single quotes around your parameter in the query, which PDO takes care of for you. Just remove the quotes around :name.

Comment: Will confirm when I get a chance, and will choose answer if it works. Thanks!